# Binding Nested List

Tags: c#

I am trying to bind the following

```
namespace Webservice_Test.MOdel
{
    public class TestModelcs
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public List<Address> Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
}
```

this is my code but I keep getting an error when it gets to address

```
List<TestModelcs> cp = new List<TestModelcs>();
TestModelcs tm = new TestModelcs();
tm.FirstName = "fm";
tm.ID = 1;
tm.Address[1].Street = "st1";
tm.Address[1].City = "city1";
cp.Add(tm);
```

The error I get is

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Webservice Test.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 3):

In the code change the TestModelcs class to

```
public class TestModelcs
{
     public TestModelcs()
     {
        this.Address = new List<Address>();
     }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Address { get; set; }
}
```

You need to initialize the list object inside the constructor of the container class to create an object of the list. Else a null reference exception will occur.

An alternative in C# 6.0 to initialize the Address list

```
public class TestModelcs
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Address { get; set; } = new List<Address>();
}
```

Comment: Address { get; set; } = new List<Address>()

Answer (score 1):

change your code with the following:

```
List<TestModelcs> cp = new List<TestModelcs>();
TestModelcs tm = new TestModelcs();
tm.FirstName = "fm";
tm.ID = 1;
tm.Address=new List<Address>();
tm.Address.Add(new Address())
tm.Address[0].Street = "st1";
tm.Address[0].City = "city1";
cp.Add(tm);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the list somewhere, like in the constructor.

```
public class TestModelcs
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Address { get; set; }

    public TestModelcs()
    {
        Address = new List<Address>();
    }
}
```